# OutofMemoryException in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a desktop application in vb.net 2003. Here when we load the main screen we find an unhandled exception showing out of memory, but we are able to continue working off the form and retrieving data. It works fine, but the image is not getting loaded.

In the main screen we have a background image loaded, one of the images is animated. Please can anyone help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And your post is "OutOfCode". Please post a fragment of load event code.

Comment: @ShinyManu - Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please review [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for tips on how to ask [the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Comment: GDI+ likes to throw OOM for reasons that have little to do with running out of memory.  But forgetting to use Dispose() when 'animating' is certainly a good way to get the exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading an image via `Image.FromFile`, the MSDN documentation says that an OOM exception is thrown for attempts to load an invalid image file or for images whose pixel formats are not supported by GDI+.

Since you mention that you are able to carry on running your application, but the image is not showing, this sounds like a possible culprit.